# Why is a public copy-constructor required when assigning the temporary return object to a reference?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, rvo

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass&)
    {
        x = 1;
    }
public:
    int x;
    MyClass(MyClass&&)
    {
        x = 2;
    }
    static const MyClass f()
    {
        return MyClass();
    }
};

int main()
{
    const MyClass& p = MyClass::f();
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile on VC++ 2010.

```
error C2248: 'MyClass::MyClass: cannot access private member declared in class 'MyClass'
```

I believe it has something to do with the RVO, but I'd like to better understand what it's doing. I see no reason the copy constructor must be called.

Here's what I would expect:

- Enter f()
- Call default constructor
- Call move constructor to return the object (possibly optimized out by RVO)
- Assign temporary return object to the reference p

In fact, if I make the copy constructor public, it compiles and works exactly that way. The copy constructor is never called. The final value of x is 0.

Comment: Note that in your example in `main`, that would not invoke a copy constructor, instead it would use the [`copy assignment operator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator)

Comment: @Cyber: No, that's an initialisation, and uses a constructor whether or not it contains `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with C++03 rules. In C++03, assigning initially a temporary to a reference *may* copy the temporary.

Starting with C++11, that behavior is gone and no copy is done anymore.

Comment: Ah, I see that I overstepped then. Even though MSVC++ 2010 has some features of C++11 (notably rvalue refs), it is based on C++03, is it not?

Comment: You say it _may_ copy it. Under what conditions? Is it just which compiler, or are there other conditions?

Comment: I don't know on what standard it is "based" or what exactly that would mean. Since prior versions of MSVC++ existed long before C++11 had been released, and I would bet that they haven't rewritten their code for C++11, I would say that in a sense of the word "based" - yes it is "based" on C++03.

Comment: @Veggie for the technical details, you can consult http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#391, which is the defect report that shows the most important parts of the discussion leading to the change in C++11 and the rationale for the old behavior in C++03.

Comment: I've confirmed what you've said by testing my case in MSVC++ 2013, which is closer to C++11 compliant. It works as expected.